# How can I gracefully stop loading a package based on Mathematica version number?

Tags: packages

I recently shared some work with a colleague and realized that his having v12 caused issues, as I used some new-to-13 functions.

## How can I put a requirement for a minimum version into my package?

Here's an example `Futuristic.m` which `Exit[]`s upon realizing that I don't have v14 yet.

```
BeginPackage["Futuristic`"]

amazingFeature::usage="Whoa, dude.  
The functionality of this amazingFeature requires the latest Mathematica";

Begin["`Private`"]

lowestAllowedVersionNumber=14;
If[$VersionNumber < lowestAllowedVersionNumber,
    (
        Print["Loading the Futuristic package failed.  
               You need version "<>ToString[lowestAllowedVersionNumber]];
        Exit[]
    )
]

amazingFeature[x_]:=2 x

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

If, from a front-end kernel I do

```
Get["~/Desktop/Futuristic.m"]
```

it prints the error message and exits.

However, exiting is extremely aggressive design.  If I were in the middle of a calculation with a lot of definitions already built up, I'd be upset if the kernel exited.

Upon trying to load I want one of two things to happen:

- If the user has a recent-enough version, just load as expected.
- Otherwise:

  - Print a message telling the user that loading the `Futuristic` package failed, as above.
  - Quickly exit from the package definition.
  - Do not leave the user with any definitions from inside the `Futuristic` package at all.  That includes (in the above example) `lowestAllowedVersionNumber`.

Is that possible?  Is there a "standard" way to do it?

I thought one way would be to add a requirement to the `BeginPackage` statement, such as ``` BeginPackage["Futuristic``",{"FunctionPoles``"}] ```.  Since `FunctionPoles` is new in 13, if it's available then the user has v13.  Trying ``` BeginPackage["Futuristic``",{"FancyNewv14Function``"}] ``` does produce error messages, but doesn't prevent the package from being loaded, `amazingFeature` is still available.  I can wrap it in `Check` and exit,

```
Check[BeginPackage["Futuristic`","FancyNewv14Context`"],Exit[]];
```

but this still uses the aggressive `Exit[]`, rather than gracefully preventing the rest of the package from being processed.

Comment: Distribute your package as a paclet. Then you can include the minimum version as metadata. The paclet will not load in incompatible versions. You really should do this, but if for some reason you don't want to, you can check `$VersionNumber` and abort if it's too low.

Comment: Example: https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/blob/master/IGraphM/PacletInfo.m#L8  The more modern way is to use `WolframVersion`, but `MathematicaVersion` will be recognized by even very old Mathematica (including version 9), which is why I prefer it. Example of a more rudimentary check: https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/blob/master/IGraphM/Kernel/init.m#L27

Comment: A sternly worded warning message might be nicer, in case someone with lower versions can still squeeze out some functionality.

Comment: @Szabolcs from looking at the Kernel/init.m in the IGraphM package you do something similar when testing for `$CloudEvaluation`.  I didn't know about `Abort[]`.

Then I can do `Check[BeginPackage["Futuristic``","FancyNewv14Context``"],EndPackage[];Print["Message :("]; Abort[]];`.

But perhaps now is a good time to learn the whole paclet business...

Comment: @ChrisK Well, it depends. With packages that use LibraryLink, there is a risk of a kernel crash in older versions. Older Mathematica versions simply crashes when trying to load a library compiled for a newer version. Luckily this was fixed, but there are other crash-risky ways of failure

Answer (score 9):

I second the suggestion of [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs), in that paclets provide a clean declarative way of WL version - aware distribution of your package. You can have multiple paclets for the same package, with different paclet version *and* minimal WL version indicated in their `PacletInfo` file, and paclet manager will automatically pick the paclet with maximal paclet version, compatible with WL version requirements, at installation time.

OTOH, using `Abort[]` doesn't look like a good solution in this case, since it is too disruptive.

---

Should you insist on your suggested scheme, I can offer some solution, which should work when the package is loaded with `Get` or `Needs` from a file. It will not work when the package is evaluated interactively in the FrontEnd, however.

Here is a tiny package `AbortPackageLoad.m`, which you can place next to your own package, or anywhere else on `$Path`:

```
BeginPackage["AbortPackageLoad`"]

AbortPackageLoad::usage = 
"AbortPackageLoad[context, metadata] attempts to gracefully abort loading \
of a package from where it is called. The second optional argument may \
contain the metadata association, describing the specific reason for abort \
and associated information."

AbortPackageLoad::genfail = 
"Loading of package `1` failed for certain internal reason";

AbortPackageLoad::invldver = 
"Loading of package `1` failed. You need version `2`";


Begin["`Private`"]

$reasonMessageMap = <|
  "general" -> Function[Message[AbortPackageLoad::genfail]]
  ,
  "invalid_version" -> Function[
    {context, meta},
    Message[AbortPackageLoad::invldver, context, meta["RequiredVersion"]]
  ]
|>

removeContext[cont_String] /; MemberQ[Contexts[], cont] := 
  Quiet @ Remove[Evaluate[cont <> "*"]]

AbortPackageLoad[context_][metadata_ : <|"FailureReason" -> "general"|>] :=
  With[
    {private = context <> "Private`"}
    ,
    $reasonMessageMap[Lookup[metadata, "FailureReason", "general"]][
      context, metadata
    ];
    If[$InputFileName =!= "",
      Scan[removeContext, {context, private}];    
      Unprotect[$Packages];
      $Packages = DeleteCases[$Packages, context];
      Protect[$Packages];
      If[$Context === private, End[]];
      If[$Context === context, EndPackage[]];
      $ContextPath = DeleteCases[$ContextPath, context];
      Return[$Failed, Get]
    ];
]

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

Here is one way to use it in your package:

```
BeginPackage["Futuristic`"]

amazingFeature::usage = "Whoa, dude.  
The functionality of this amazingFeature requires the latest \
Mathematica";

`Private`abort = AbortPackageLoad`AbortPackageLoad[$Context];

Begin["`Private`"]

Needs["AbortPackageLoad`"]

lowestAllowedVersionNumber = 14;

If[$VersionNumber < lowestAllowedVersionNumber, 
  abort[<|
    "FailureReason" -> "invalid_version", 
    "RequiredVersion" -> "14+"
  |>]
];

amazingFeature[x_] := 2 x

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

---

**EDIT**

In response to the suggestion by Szabolcs in comments, I have modified the `AbortPackageLoad` function, so that it can also be used at the very top of the package file, before `BeginPackage[]` statement - if that's desirable / preferable. Or even inside the package, after `BeginPackage[]` but before `` Begin["`Private`"] ``. This is how it could be used in this fashion:

```
Block[{$ContextPath},
  Needs["AbortPackageLoad`"];
  If[$VersionNumber < 14, 
    AbortPackageLoad`AbortPackageLoad["Futuristic`"][<|
      "FailureReason" -> "invalid_version", 
      "RequiredVersion" -> "14+"
    |>]
  ];
]

BeginPackage["Futuristic`"]

...

EndPackage[]
```

**END EDIT**

---

The way `AbortPackageLoad` works is to clean and remove the public and private contexts of the package being loaded, then clean up global variables `$Package` and `$ContextPath`, ensure that package contexts are properly closed (so that `$Context` will point back to whatever context was there before loading your package), and finally, crucially, uses two-argument `Return` to return from `Get` early. Since `Needs` calls `Get` internally, this will work for `Needs` too.

When package is loaded from file, this mechanism works, because the file is parsed line by line, and complete expressions further in the file are not sent to evaluation early. When you execute the package from a FrontEnd cell, this will not work, because expressions further in the cell will still be parsed and send for evaluation. There are some ways to cancel the rest of evaluation queue, but I wasn't convinced that they are robust enough for this use case, so I excluded FrontEnd evaluation use case with the check `If[$InputFileName =!= "", ...]`.

I don't see obvious cases where the above solution will break for non-MX packages loaded with `Get` / `Needs`, but OTOH I would still hesitate to use it in production code.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do the version check _before_ the `BeginPackage`? Then it wouldn't be necessary to run `End[]` and `EndPackage[]` within the abort function. I had an abort function that did this in the past, but then I just switched to doing the check before the `BeginPackage`, most conveniently before `Kernel/init.m`. The tricky part is that such a check must only use built-in symbols, otherwise it will create new symbols in the ``Global` `` context. Even `With[{x = ...}, x^2]` or similar would create `x` in ``Global` ``.

Comment: @Szabolcs In this particular case, you are probably right. And of course also in general, your suggestion about using paclets is probably the best solution here. I was trying to match the request of the OP as close as possible, and was assuming that the version information for the check might only become available at some point during the loading of the package. I have slightly modified the implementation of `AbortPackageLoad`, so that it can be also used in the fashion you suggested.